# Alignment of injected buttons on sap.m.table

Tags: sapui5

I have a table (`sap.m.table`) and am using the delete table mode (`mode="Delete"`) and am also including the edit feature by setting the `ColumnListItem` type to (`type="DetailAndActive"`)

```
<Table id="usersTable"  mode="Delete"
```

...

```
<ColumnListItem type="DetailAndActive" vAlign="Middle" detailPress="onEdit" highlight="{= ${users>EmailConfirmed} === true ? 'None' : 'Error'}">
```

I have 2 lines per row as I have an objectidentifier as 1 of the cells:

```
<ObjectIdentifier title="{users>Email}" text="last: {path: 'users>LastLoggedOnUtcDate', formatter: '.formatDateTime'}"/>
```

When displaying I get the following outcome:

[image]

The button alignment is out - the edit button is vertically aligned at the top while the delete button is vertically aligned in the center.
As you can see I have set vAlign to Middle on the ColumnListItem.
I would appreciate any help for aligning the edit button in the center too?
Thanks!

Comment: why dont you use the mode "SingleSelect" and add a edit and delete button to the tabels toolbar? its a workaround not a fix, but looks nice too

Comment: also can you please post the code of you entire table? i use an object identifier in one of mine too, but the other columns still are in the middle of the row not in the upper part like in your screenshot

Comment: sorry - I came right on this - I appeared to be having a caching issue - I do apologise and appreciate the help.

Comment: happens, but as a tipp open your debuggersetting and look for the flag "disable cache (while dev tools are open)" since while developing you most likely have the dev tools open to peek at the console or set some breakpoint it solves most caching issues